# Wpf Button Programmatically no effect

Tags: wpf, button, background, border

I have the following code:

```
var cellButton = new Button( ) { Background = new SolidColorBrush( 
Colors.Transparent ), BorderThickness = new Thickness( 0 ) };
```

Then I have a stackpanel

```
var stack = new StackPanel( ) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical, 
VerticalAlignment= VerticalAlignment.Stretch, HorizontalAlignment= 
HorizontalAlignment.Stretch };

cellButton.Content = stack;
```

The button is the problem here. This seems to have no affect at all, am I doing something wrong?
I can still see the default Boder and Default background(Gray) of the button.
I even tried to change the color to something else, nothing.

So as you can see I had to strecht the stackpanel horizontal and vertical to overtake the buttons background as a dirty solution, but I can still see the border of the button.

Comment: Did you try setting the border `opacity` to 0?

Comment: Why are you setting the Content of the Button to an empty StackPanel?

Comment: In my code its not empty, I just didnt want to post all the code for the stackpanel. The background of the stackpane is white. And streching the stackpanel helps

Comment: So what is your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you 100% sure that what you see on the screen is the `Button` created by the code you have posted here? Not only it would be transparent and have no content, since you have set `Button.Content` to an empty `StackPanel`, but it will have `Height=auto` and `Width=auto` (by default), so in this case it will be set to 0.

Try setting your `Button.Background` and `Button.BorderBrush` to another color (e.g. red) to test if it works. Also set `Button.Width` and `Button.Height` to hardcoded values just for testing.